# How to extract an associative array function argument AND pass a component of the array by reference in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

For scalability purposes, I usually pass arguments to a function as an associative array (since the array is easily changed) and `extract()` in the function:

```
$a = 'a'; ....... $n = 'n';

$arg = array(
    'a' => $a,
     .
     .
    'n' => $n
);

function doStuff($arg) {
    extract($arg);
    // etc
}
```

But I have failed trying to do the same but passing a variable(s) component of $arg by reference. For example, to get the following result:

```
$a = 'x';
```

I can do this:

```
$a = 'a';

function doStuff(&$var) {
    $var = 'x';
}

doStuff($a); 

echo $a; // ---> echoes 'x'
```

How do you do this using the extract method? For example, the following echoes 'a', not 'x':

```
$a = 'a'; ....... $n = 'n';

$arg = array(
    'a' => $a,
     .
     .
    'n' => $n
);

function doStuff(&$arg) {
    extract($arg);

    $a = 'x'; 
}

doStuff($arg);

echo $a; // echoes 'a'
```

I have also tried this:

```
$arg = array(
    'a' => &$a,
     .
     .
    'n' => $n
);
```

*Is it possible to use `extract()` here to make (in this case) `$a` echo as 'x' ?*

Comment: *"`echo doStuff($a); // ---> echoes 'x'`"* -- really? What part of the statement displays the *"x"*? The `doStuff()` function doesn't display anything and `echo` displays what `doStuff()` [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)s, i.e. absolutely nothing.

Comment: sorry- going to edit - was in a hurry

Comment: Try using the `EXTR_REFS` flag. See the manual for [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing the **$arg** array by reference it is the **$arg** array that has to be changed to reflect this change out of the function scope, so I think you need to use combine or build the **$arg** back any other way with the changed values:

```
function doStuff(&$arg) {
    extract($arg);
    $a = 'x'; 
    $arg = combine(...);
    // OR
    $arg = ['a' => $a];
}
```

To see it running:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/70b4b5e7d90b829588aa0fd0b3caf621fa1b5ed3

Comment: I don't care about the array...I want a component of the array, which is the 'a' key of $arg, i.e., $a

Answer (score 0):

I used the comment from Patrick Q for the correct answer:

```
$a = 'a'; ....... $n = 'n';

$arg = array(
    'a' => &$a,
     .
     .
    'n' => $n
);

function doStuff($arg) {
    extract($arg, EXTR_REFS);

    $a = 'x'; 
}

doStuff($arg);

echo $a; // echoes 'x'
```